# Сортировка данных БД MySql и импорт

Tags: mysql, innodb

Столкнулся с вопросом, можно ли сортировать `ORDER BY` в `MySQL` по принципу, который опишу далее.
Есть столбец, который указывает на категорию посетителя. Категории такие:

> A+, A, B, C

и т.д.

Стандартно 
`SELECT * FROM db ORDER BY cat` 
дает результат :

> А, А+, В, С

Мне нужно чтобы `А+` был первой категорией в сортировке.

Что можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны разные варианты. Например:

1. Поменять тип колонки "категория" на ENUM: `category ENUM('A+', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D')` - тогда обычная сортировка по `ORDER BY category ASC` будет использовать указанный порядок.  Это будет работать только в том случае, если четко ограничены и заранее известны варианты.
2. Использовать `CASE WHEN ... END` для сортировки:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM myTable
   ORDER BY (CASE WHEN category='A+' THEN 0 ELSE ASCII(UCASE(category) END) ASC
   ```

Comment: Aleks, благодарю Вас за ответ. Вы мне помогли :)

Comment: @Евгений  Вариант 3: `order by reverse(category)` задом наперед +A будет первым, остальные буквы как обычно :)

Answer (score 2):

Есть другой вариант, который будет работать лучше, если ваша система будет расширяться, а также соответствует [третьей нормальной форме](https://habrahabr.ru/post/254773/). Создаём дополнительную таблицу categories, в которой делаем поля id и cat_name. В эту таблицу заносим все возможные категории. В таблице myTable вместо поля category делаем поле cat_id, в которое заносится номер нужной категории. После этого делаем связь из поля categories.id в поле myTable.cat_id "один-ко-многим". Связь обеспечит невозможность добавления в таблицу myTable записи с несуществующей категорией.

Теперь о выборке с сортировкой. Я могу ошибаться с особенностями синтаксиса MySql, но суть такова:

```
SELECT myTable.id, categories.cat_name
FROM myTable
    JOIN categories ON myTable.cat_id=categories.id
ORDER BY myTable.cat_id
```

В этом случае категории отсортируются в том порядке, в каком они введены в таблицу categories.

Comment: Я выбрал, на мой взгляд, самый простой вариант из предложенных.
Сделал тип колонки "категория" `ENUM`.
Так как я знаю какие есть категории и то, что они не добавляются, написал в Значении свои категории в том порядке, в котором должен быть фильтр (А+, А, В, С...) и все работает как нужно.

Comment: @Евгений,  тем не менее обязательно прочитайте про нормализацию. Это поможет вам, когда ваши базы данных будут более развёрнуты, объёмны, масштабны.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, обязательно прочту!
Я новичок в этом деле, называемом программированием :)
Благодарен за любое наставление!